# why my application does not start in landscape mode in some virtual devices

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have set screenOrientation to landscape in my AndroidManifest.xml. This works fine for most emulated devices in Android Studio.

```
   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"

            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

and in OnCreate

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
FullscreenActivity.context = getApplicationContext();
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

But for Nexus 9 this doesn't work and my app stays in portait mode , which results in making my images distorted.

[image]

i would expect to be like this :

[image]

Startup orientation is portrait for both of them. I want to have a landscape only application

Comment: did you try to make layout file in 'layout-land' folder, land means landscape mode. You can find more details from these links: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources#resource_merging and https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#Compatibility

Answer (score 0):

A solution i have found is to force a minimum aspect ratio to 1.3 with

```
android:minAspectRatio="1.3"
```

and to set

```
android:resizeableActivity="false"
```

With these options the activity starts within a part of the screen if it is in portrait mode and so the images do not get distorted

[image]